# AngularJS arrays and incremental memory usage

Tags: angularjs, arrays, memory, timeout

I am using a $timeout to periodically pull tabular data from the back end and display them in HTML. I suspect every time I get an update, a new memory segment is being allocated in the browser for the JSON array. I was wondering if that's the case. Below are simplified fragments of code.

**HTML**`

```
<tr ng-repeat="measurement in measurementResults">
  <td>{{measurement.type}}</td>
  <td>{{measurement.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
function startTimeout() {
  MeasurementService.getNewMeasurements(function (measuredData) {
    $scope.measurementResults = measuredData;

  });

  $timeout(startTimeout, 15000);

}

startTimeout();
```

This is the JSON data array format that I am passing to the $scope.

```
[{"type":type1,"value":10}, {"type":type2,"value":20}, {"type":type3,"value":80}]
```

Is $scope.measurementResults pointing to a new memory location (or creating a new array) every time I receive the measuredData from the service callback?

**EDIT:**
I am attaching two screenshots of memory graphs, the first one shows how the nodes go up and down (green line), and the second one shows how the line becomes flat after applying "track by $index"

[image]

[image: Memory usage for nodes stable]

Comment: Yes, everytime the XHR uses new memory to receive the data from the server. The [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) points `$scope.measurementResults` to the new memory and the old memory is freed for garbage collection.

Comment: I observe incremental memory usage, for example, in Chrome and Firefox, on every page where i have this sort of periodic calls. I don't know if that's due to my code, or if that's because the browser not releasing the old memory. I do not observe this in Safari though, which remains stable.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? There were `ng-repeat` memory leak issues that were fixed with Version1.3. For more information, see [GitHub AngularJS Issue #10121](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10121).

Comment: It's version 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
//You may use track by for performance boost
<tr ng-repeat="measurement in measurementResults track by $index">
  <td>{{measurement.type}}</td>
  <td>{{measurement.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Great, track by $index significantly dropped the memory usage, from almost 1 MB leaking at each call down to 10-20 KB at each call. I had multiple nested ng-repets and this "track by" did a very good job. However, it appears even angular 1.5 still has this memory leaking issue with rg-repeat, as georgeawg mentioned.

Comment: The screenshots are from a lightweight test page, by the way, not the real one.

Comment: Still You can use one way binding for performance boost..please refer this doc..sure it make sense & help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480548/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bind-vs-one-time-binding-in-angular