# Can anyone explain the difference between expression, ng-bind and ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

I am very confuse between expression {{}}, ng-bind and ng-model. please explain with example if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-bind` and `ng-model` both are the inbuilt directives in Angular.

While `ng-bind` helps you to bind a value to `innerHTML` of an element, `ng-model` helps you bind the data to the interactive elements (i.e. `<input>`, `<checkbox>`, `<textarea>`), you got it..

**Usage:**

**ng-bind**

If you have 
`$scope.textFromComponent = "Superman"` in your controller.

`<span ng-bind="textFromComponent"></span>` binds this value within this span element.

**{{ }}**

The same behaviour can be achieved using `{{}}`.

These set of curly-brackets are called Interpolation directives and they work as a short-hand to `ng-bind`. While using them you no more need to write ng-bind rather you directly bind them. Like:

`<span>{{textFromComponent}}</span>`

**ng-model**

`<input ng-model="textFromComponent" />`

binds this value to the `value` property of your input element. This binds the value **two-way** which means if you make any changes to `$scope.textFromComponent` in your code, it will reflect on screen automatically. At the same time, if user makes any change to it ( since they are interactive elements, user can change them) the changed value will be passed to your code.

Answer (score 0):

- `{{ data }}` will be replaced by the value of `data` variable in the related scope. It updates automatically as `data` inside `scope` changes. So, we say,
  `{{ data }}` is binded to the variable `data`. However, if `data` is html, angularjs will automatically escape the markup for security reasons.
- `ng-bind` binds the 'content' of element. Like, in case of `<div ng-bind="data" ></div>` the `div` will be filled with value of `data` variable. In this case markup present in `data` will be rendered too.(using `ng-bind-html`)
- `ng-model` simply binds the value of html element to some variable in the scope. Like: in case of `<input ng-model="data" />` variable `data` inside scope will have the value of input.

Hope that helps !

Comment: 1 more question is that expression {{}} is one way binding or two way?

Comment: {{}} is a one-way binding scope - - > view

Comment: {{}} is expression for binding values in angular if you use {{}} expression means you r using two way binding and {{::}} is one way binding expression for angular..please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480548/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bind-vs-one-time-binding-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind` and `{{}}` are basically the same. However, before your application fully loads, sometimes `{{}}` are visible. ng-bind usually looks a little nicer before everything finishes loading. `{{}}` is easier, but has some limitations that will require ng-bind. `<span ng-bind="something"></span>` is your friend.

There are some contexts that `{{}}` will not work. For example when your data is markup.

ng-model is used for input.

All three are used in the example below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <p>Please Enter Your Name</p><input type="text" ng-model="yourName" />
  <p>Hello <span ng-bind="yourName"></span>, this is an ng-bind!</p>
  <p>Hello {{yourName}}, this is bind in brackets</p>
</div>
```