# change context in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

lets say in my controller I have the following object :

```
$scope.person = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"};
```

In my view, I can bind it this way :

```
<div>
 {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}
</div>
```

but is there a way I could do something like this to avoid rewriting "person" everytime?

```
<div ng-model="person">
 {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
</div>
```

Comment: firstly you can not bind `ng-model` to `div`. try use one way data binding for this

Comment: I know ng-model does not work.  I just gave that as an example.  How one way binding would fix my issue.  Can you give an example?

Comment: please visit [this](https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/)

Comment: this has nothing to do with what I'd like to achieve

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480548/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bind-vs-one-time-binding-in-angular)

Comment: Hadi... It has nothing to do with one way binding..... I need a way to change the context of a specific div to avoid having to write the variable name in my binding...

Comment: If you are trying to limit code there is no way to do this in Angular.

Comment: Why do you not want to repeat 'person'?