# Avoid ng-repeat still using two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, one-time-binding

My web application is huge and I often use `ng-repeat` to get list of datas. This leads slow performance, sometimes very annoying. I know different ways to avoid the `ng-repeat` but these ways suggests to use the One-time binding trick! I can't do it because my application needs to get the datas always updated. So, is there any other way to speed up the `ng-repeat`? I'm still using a pagination to display my datas by the way. Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code example? Just to see the way you are fetching data and gluing it to the view...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between ng-bind vs one time binding in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480548/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bind-vs-one-time-binding-in-angular) - answer shows one time binding, one way binding, and two way binding.

Comment: If you are using nested ng-repeats and filters it can drastically slow down your app (depends on number of watchers).
@ShayanKhan is one of easiest solutions you can get.

Comment: Did my answer work? If so, please select it as a valid one

Answer (score 2):

First, use `<div ng-repeat x in objects track by $index>` Then, use :: (exactly as shown) for the variables where you don’t want two way binding.

Something like:

`{{::object.name}}`

I’m on a phone so can’t give you the exact syntax.

Let me know if you can’t get it to work and i’ll give you the exact syntax.